# Geopackage in Offline Maps

Tags: maps, offline, geopackage

I just wanted to ask around if you have already made any experiences in the usage of the format Geopackage in offline maps (on mobile devices).

Am starting to get into it but can't find much information about the technical implementation of geopackages in map applications. Therefore, would be glad for any hints.